# How to handle hyphens in pec::pec function

Tags: r, prediction, curve

I am trying to use the `pec::pec` function and one of my variables has a hyphen:

```
# list of all models so far
models <- list("CoxPH_mboost" = coxph_mboost_model,
               "rfsrc_lrs" = lrs_rfsrc_fit,
               "rfsrc_brier" = brier_rfsrc_fit,
               "ctree" = fit.ctree,
               "cforst" = fit.cforest,
               "cox_lasso_alpha_min" = fit.lasso.min,
               "cox_lasso_alpha_1se" = fit.lasso.1se)

# remove models that could not be generated
models[sapply(models, is.null)] <- NULL 

pec <- pec::pec(object = models,
                formula = as.formula(total.formula), 
                data = combined_data_sub, 
                exact = TRUE,
                splitMethod = "BootCv", 
                B = 500)

# error I am getting
Error in eval(predvars, data, callenv) : object 'MT-ATP6' not found

# 1 column (MT-ATP6) in the input dataframe has a hyphen
"MT-ATP6"               "GAPDH"                 "GH1"                   "MB"                                

# I have added back ticks to the variables in total formula like this
"Surv(surv_days, surv_status_recode) ~ `MT-ATP6` + `GAPDH` + `GH1` + `MB` (and so on)
```

Comment: I think the simplest solution is to change all dashes into underscores in your data. I do that routinely at the stage of importing data, otherwise you will get all sorts of problems. Given that you have not created [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is hard for me to say how to do it exactly.

Comment: You are right, I thought so too. Apologies for not providing a reproducible example, I will add that shortly. The issue is that I have been running these models for about 10 days (it is a large dataset) and all the models worked by adding the back-ticks to the hyphenated variable in the input formula, so I had assumed the final pec function would also work. Looks like it doesn't. At this point, the easiest thing I have found is removing the hyphenated variable from the "total.formula" and it seems to be working. Your solution seems to be the one that is most acceptable.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry to hear that. Well, I would probably start looking into the models and replacing the dashes semi-manually.